# How to get View like Google Fit app

Tags: android, view, android-custom-view

[image]

I found this view in google fit app but i want to know How can i achieve this view in android.

Comment: Good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 2):

you can tweeek this library for  [CircleProgress](https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress)

for pull to refresh  use [this](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh)